# How to apply a wall shear stress in abaqus?

Tags: abaqus, openfoam

I have run CFD simulations in openFOAM. Of course the two loads a fluid can impart on a body is 1) pressure, and 2) shear. I can easily apply the pressure stresses as a load on the surface of the structure in Abaqus. But I am really struggling with how to apply the wall shear stress load. Is there any advice on how I could apply a wall shear stress to a structure in Abaqus?

It feels like it should be a common practice to apply a wall shear stress load, so I am sorry if this is a basic solution. I am very new to Abaqus.

Is there a shear stress load option which I am just not seeing? Or do I need to program a wall shear stress load myself?

And yes, I know FSI is the best option for what I am trying to do, but I have been told we do not have the computer resources required for FSI. So I am manually running CFD and taking the results and applying them to FEA.

Thank you for any and all help.

I have tried following Abaqus tutorials, the Abaqus manual, and the Abaqus sub-routine manual. I can find a lot of info for shear strains, but little on shear stresses.